# Using both IF ELSE and CASE within a WHILE loop

Tags: bash, loops, if-statement, while-loop

The goal is to be able to manually select a file process order, and if the user is not at the computer then let the script select based upon the quantity of files to process.

a) Many files -gt 5 then process smallest files first

b) 5 or less then process the oldest file first

I started simple with just CASE and that is working.

Next I introduced an IF which is also working.

```
CountMp4=$(ls *.mp4 | wc -l)
while :
do
  read -t50 -p "Select a File Processing Order - [A]lpha [O]ldest [N]ewest [L]argest [S]mallest: "
  if [ $? -gt 0 ]; then
    SelectedFileName=$( ls -rt *.mp4 | head -1 ) && echo -e "No Option Selected\nWill use the Oldest file: $SelectedFileName" && break
  fi
  case $REPLY in
  [aA]*)
    SelectedFileName=$( ls *.mp4 | head -1 ) && echo "Alphabetical: $SelectedFileName" && break
    ;;
  [oO]*)
    SelectedFileName=$( ls -rt *.mp4 | head -1 ) && echo "Oldest: $SelectedFileName" && break
    ;;
  [nN]*)
    SelectedFileName=$( ls -t *.mp4 | head -1 ) && echo "Newest: $SelectedFileName" && break
    ;;
  [lL]*)
    SelectedFileName=$( ls -S *.mp4 | head -1 ) && echo "Largest: $SelectedFileName" && break
    ;;
  [sS]*)
    SelectedFileName=$( ls -rS *.mp4 | head -1 ) && echo "Smallest: $SelectedFileName" && break
    ;;
  *) echo "Please enter A, O, N, L or S"
     ;;
  esac
done
```

Now I am trying to introduce an ELSE to the IF, but this is where I am stuck.

Perhaps I am going about the solution in the wrong way.

Any guidance is appreciated.

```
CountMp4=$(ls *.mp4 | wc -l)
while :
do
  read -t50 -p "Select a File Processing Order - [A]lpha [O]ldest [N]ewest [L]argest [S]mallest: "
  if [ $? -gt 0 ] && [ $CountMp4 -gt 5 ]; then
    SelectedFileName=$( ls -rS *.mp4 | head -1 ) && echo -e "No Option Selected\nMany files, using the Smallest file: $SelectedFileName" && break
    else
    SelectedFileName=$( ls -rt *.mp4 | head -1 ) && echo -e "No Option Selected\nWill use the Oldest file: $SelectedFileName" && break
  fi
  case $REPLY in
  [aA]*)
    SelectedFileName=$( ls *.mp4 | head -1 ) && echo "Alphabetical: $SelectedFileName" && break
    ;;
  [oO]*)
    SelectedFileName=$( ls -rt *.mp4 | head -1 ) && echo "Oldest: $SelectedFileName" && break
    ;;
  [nN]*)
    SelectedFileName=$( ls -t *.mp4 | head -1 ) && echo "Newest: $SelectedFileName" && break
    ;;
  [lL]*)
    SelectedFileName=$( ls -S *.mp4 | head -1 ) && echo "Largest: $SelectedFileName" && break
    ;;
  [sS]*)
    SelectedFileName=$( ls -rS *.mp4 | head -1 ) && echo "Smallest: $SelectedFileName" && break
    ;;
  *) echo "Please enter A, O, N, L or S"
     ;;
  esac
done
```

When I introduce ELSE to the IF, I break the CASE.

Comment: What do you mean by "break the CASE"?

Comment: The assignment to `SelectedFileName` will always succeed (simply  because `head` will always have exit code 0. The `echo` will also succeed (why should it fail?). Thererfore, the `break` will always be executed and the loop will be terminated without entering the `case` statement.

Comment: How about removing the `break`? Also, [don’t parse output from `ls`](https://www.shellcheck.net/wiki/SC2010).

Comment: As the [tag:bash] tag you used instructs - "For shell scripts with syntax or other errors, please check them at https://shellcheck.net before posting them here. ".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't create 2 separate ways of getting results, just let the one `case` statement handle it:

```
CountMp4=$(ls *.mp4 | wc -l)
while :
do
  read -t50 -p "Select a File Processing Order - [A]lpha [O]ldest [N]ewest [L]argest [S]mallest: "
  if [ $? -gt 0 ]; then
    if [ $CountMp4 -gt 5 ]; then
      echo -e "No Option Selected, many files, use the Smallest file"
      REPLY='S'
    else
      echo -e "No Option Selected, few files, use the Oldest file"
      REPLY='O'
    fi
  fi
  case $REPLY in
  [aA]*)
    SelectedFileName=$( ls *.mp4 | head -1 ) && echo "Alphabetical: $SelectedFileName" && break
    ;;
  [oO]*)
    SelectedFileName=$( ls -rt *.mp4 | head -1 ) && echo "Oldest: $SelectedFileName" && break
    ;;
  [nN]*)
    SelectedFileName=$( ls -t *.mp4 | head -1 ) && echo "Newest: $SelectedFileName" && break
    ;;
  [lL]*)
    SelectedFileName=$( ls -S *.mp4 | head -1 ) && echo "Largest: $SelectedFileName" && break
    ;;
  [sS]*)
    SelectedFileName=$( ls -rS *.mp4 | head -1 ) && echo "Smallest: $SelectedFileName" && break
    ;;
  *) echo "Please enter A, O, N, L or S"
     ;;
  esac
done
```

BUT you have several other issues to clean up in your script, start by copy/pasting it into http://shellcheck.net and fixing what that tool tells you about and then consider doing something like this, untested:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

selectFile() {
    printf '%s\n' "${files[@]}" | sort "$@" | head -1 | cut -f3-
}

readarray -t files < <(find . -name '*.mp4' -printf '%A@\t%s\t%P\n')

if (( ${#files[@]} > 5 )); then
    dfltReply='S'
else
    dfltReply='O'
fi

while :
do
    if ! read ....; then
        printf 'read failed, using default %s\n' "$dfltReply" >&2
        REPLY="$dfltReply"
    fi
    case $REPLY in
    [aA]*) SelectedFileName=$(selectFile -k3) && break ;;
    [oO]*) SelectedFileName=$(selectFile -nrk1) && break ;;
...
    *) printf 'Please enter A, O, N, L or S\n' ;;
    esac
done
```

The main part is to use `find` to find the files, print their latest modification time, size, and name, and store that list in an array, `files[]`. From then on you just pipe the array contents to `sort` with appropriate options followed by `head` and `cut` to get the file name you need in each case.

The above is assuming your file names cannot contain newlines - if they can then change `-printf '%A@\t%s\t%P\n'` to `-printf '%A@\t%s\t%P\0'`, add the `-z` option to `sort`, `head`, and `cut` (requires GNU tools), change `printf '%s\n' "${files[@]}"` to `printf '%s\0' "${files[@]}"` and change the way `selectFile()` is implemented and called to some variation of:

```
selectFile () {
    IFS= read -d '' -r "$1" < <(
        printf '%s\0' "${files[@]}" | sort -z "$2" | head -z -n 1 | cut -z -f3-
    )
}
selectFile SelectedFileName -k3
```

because command substitution `var=$(func)` doesn't support NUL bytes in the assignment.